# Client ID is missing when I try to create a Custom Report in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I see other posts saying that I can create a custom report in Google Analytics and use client ID as a dimension but I don't have client ID as a dimension even after setting up the User-ID View.

I'm tracking the usage of a Google Data Studio Report with Google Analytics and I can see data pulling through to the User Explorer but there's no Client ID field in the Custom Report Dimension drop down box. Do I need to set up something else?

Comment: I also need to add that I can only open the User Explorer in the View where I did not set up the User-ID View and not in the view where I did the User-View set up. I'm confused

Answer (score 1):

**First**
Client id  and user id are different identifiers.
Client id is a just randomly generated UUID v4 used in GA to identity visitors. It’s stored in _ga cookie so, I.e. if I’ll visit your site from 2 different browser there will be 2 different client ids.

User id is a field to store user id from your own authentication system. You can use it for cross platform and cross browser user tracking.

**Second**
Client id aren’t one of default dimensions in GA. To have it as a dimension you have to read it from _ga cookie or from [model object](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/model-object-reference) and set it as a custom dimension.

Comment: Is it possible to read Client ID from Google Data Studio users though? I'm tracking the internal use of a Data Studio Report. My tutorial directs me to use Google Tag Manager but there's no way to copy the script with the container ID into the pages. Or is there another way maybe?